# extracting columns from dataframe with atleast three values above cutoff

Tags: r

I am new to R  programming. Need help to filter my data.For example my data set is mtcars. I want to extract columns which have at least three values above 18. How do i do that.thanks

I have used sort function but that is good only for one column each. not as a whole data frame.

Comment: Go through this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647417/8583393 and start with `mtcars > 18`. Come back if you have problems and share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the names of the columns with the following code do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

columns = mtcars %>% gather() %>% filter(value > 18) %>% count(key) %>% filter(n > 3) %>% 
select(key)
```

And then filter the dataframe with:

```
mtcars[, c(t(columns))]
```

`gather` transforms the dataframe to one that has two columns:

- key is the name of the column
- value is the value taken by the observation for the column

The value above 18 are filtered and we count the number of observations by `key` (the name of the column).

Comment: If you want to use `dplyr` you could shorten this a little: `mtcars %>% select_if(., colSums(. > 18) > 3)`

Comment: thanks markus. i tried with mtcars it is giving me the correct answer. but when i try with my dataframe i get error ONLY STRINGS CAN BE CONVERTED TO SYMBOLS.

Comment: ok i got it. after removing NA and replacing with 0 i get the desired result. thanks all .